# Form Recognizer - model for each environment?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

On our test environment we created custom Form Recognizer model. Is there a way to reuse this model on PROD environment? Prod environment is under different subscription.

I cannot find a way to somehow "export" model and move it to other environment. Do I need to create new model from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Copy Model API to copy a model between regions and subscriptions. See here for more details -
How to Copy API - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/disaster-recovery#copy-api-overview

Copy Model API reference -  https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api-v2-1-preview-2/operations/CopyCustomFormModel

Comment: "The Copy API currently does not support model IDs for composed custom models. Model compose is a preview feature in v2.1-preview.2 preview". Unfortunatelly I'm using composed model.

Comment: If you are using 2.1-preview.2 model compose is also supported in the copy model. Can you please share the error you receive when trying to copy the model ?